# TCP listener receives huge data

Tags: vb.net, tcplistener

I have two application which one is server and the other one is client written in VB.net.
both of them are running on same machine ( using 127.0.0.1 )
client only sends 5 bytes data to server for example: "farid"
but the sever app which has TCP listener receives a huge data with length of 65534 bytes.
I tried to print the received data and it printed "farid" whith lots of empty spaces in front of it
I am sure that the TCP client sends the right data, but I have no idea what happens to the data when listener receives it.

Comment: Can you post some code to show what your client and server does.

Comment: TCP is heavy... doesn't quite account for your current size, but... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613989/what-of-traffic-is-network-overhead-on-top-of-http-s-requests

Comment: What protocol are you using over the sockets? Can you post a sample of the data your sending?

Comment: I am testing this code, sever code: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1071

client code: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1070

Comment: What your debugging the server, what is the value of the clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize, is it 65534 bytes or have you read 65534 bytes of data or both.

Comment: my buffer size is 10024 but it reads 65534 bytes while the client sends 5 byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you were using has some horrible practices and mistakes in it...  =\

The receive loop in getMessage() should look more like:

```
Private Sub getMessage()
    Dim inStream(10024) As Byte
    serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
    While True
        Dim bytesRead As Integer = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, inStream.Length)
        readData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, bytesRead)
        msg()
    End While
End Sub
```

*Using the global string "readData" is a pretty bad design though!

You should read my article here closely: [A Peer-To-Peer LAN Chat Application in Visual Basic.Net using TcpClient and TcpListener](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/A_11178-A-Peer-To-Peer-LAN-Chat-Application-in-Visual-Basic-Net-using-TcpClient-and-TcpListener.html)